# Instantiating World Canvases

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate many world canvases and it gives me this error:

> UnityEngine.UI.Text.Text()' is inaccessible due to its protection
> level, UnityEngine.UI.Image.Image()' is inaccessible due to its
> protection level

I have created an prefab which contains a canvas set to world space, and I can't understand the right approach to instantiate them. here is a copy of the script:

```
public void PositionWorldCanvases ()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++) {

         Canvas can = new Canvas();
         Text text = new Text();
         Image image = new Image();

        Instantiate (canvasManager, vertices[i], Quaternion.identity);
        can = canvasManager.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas> ();
        image = can.GetComponent<Image> ();
        text = image.GetComponent<Text> ();
        text.text = "Hello World";
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a problem with instantiating, its a problem with *construction*.

`Text` and `Image` have `private` constructors, so they cannot be created out of scope using the `new` keyword, you have to attach them manually to an empty `GameObject` with a `RectTransform` and `CanvasRenderer` component. then you instantiate that object.

Comment: what do you mean out of scope? i have to attach them via script or when i create the prefab in unity? I tryed  few things but i dont know how to comunicate with the canvas prefab after its Instantiated.

Comment: What i mean is a `new Image()` can only be declared from inside of the `Image` class itself